# Data truncated in post request

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, mozilla

I use `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, in a Greasemonkey script, to post data to my server:

```
var contentodds = $("#panel").html();
// console.log(contentodds);
var formData1   = contentodds;
console.log(contentodds);

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "POST",
    url:        "http://localhost:88/quote/homes/dotest",
    data:       "SboData=" + contentodds
                // etc.
                ,
    headers:    {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-length":contentodds.length
    },
    onload:     function (response) {
        //console.log (response.responseText);
    }
} );
```

By default, Greasemonkey uses an `xmlhttprequest` object. My string data is 10,994,944 (bytes? chars?) long, but when it's posted, it's truncated to 10000 chars.

Is there is any solution to increase the data limit of the `xmlhttprequest` object in Mozilla/Greasemonkey?
I have seen that the xmlhttp request, object limit in Internet Explorer is large but not in Firefox.
Or, is there any other solution to post the data in small chunks?